# spring call controller method from a function

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi i have one controller :-

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.get)
    public String login(@RequestBody User login) throws ServletException{
  }
}
```

and i have another `GenericFilterBean` class. This is for doing some security functionalities like validating the tokens and etc.

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
     final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");

    if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            new ModelAndView("user/login");// this way i am trying to call one controller method. 
            throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid Authorization header"); // this is throws one exception. This is only for the dev purpose.
        }else {

            final String token = authHeader.substring(7);

            try {
                final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
            } catch (final SignatureException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Invalid token");
            }

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

My question is from the `doFilter` method how can i call the controller method `login`

this `new ModelAndView("user/login");` code is not working. So please suggest some way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really put login in a get request as a best practice.

Secondly, if you want your filter to validate the login, you can either use it as a middleware/as an aspect/or just write the validation method in a service class and use that instead.

If you really want to call the endpoint through the filter, you can try using the rest template.

```
String fooResourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/user/login";
User userWithLoginCredentials = new User() //Create your user object
HttpEntity<User> request = new HttpEntity<>(userWithLoginCredentials);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Foo> response = restTemplate.exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, User.class);
```

Comment: Please first understand my question. I dont want to make any rest call. I just need to call one controller method that returns the HTML page. So if you have any idea about this please help me.